# QVector::remove(int i, int count) performance when removing from the first

Tags: c++, qt, qvector

I want to use a QVector like a queue. That's because i want to access a raw pointer to data in vector and QVector puts data contiguously. So i append data in my QVector in a thread and in another thread read count elements from the first and remove them.

When you remove from the middle of a QVector the data is rearranged and many copies take place. I want to know whether data is copied when removing count elements from the begging of QVector or it have little overhead? Is there any better method for doing this?

Comment: `QVector` isn't designed for queuing elements, you should wrap your data in a `QQueue`

Comment: But i can't access to data in QQueue by a pointer.

Comment: By a pointer on what?

Comment: As I told in your another question - you should read something about data structures and they complexity. If you need fast access by index - you should use QVector, if you need fast insertion / removing you should use QLinkedList. But in most cases it's enough to use QList. What is your original problem? Where do you have performance issues? How do you analyze them?

Comment: I need to access a pointer to raw data in my container which limits my choice to QVector. Now i want to use the container like a queue which makes me to remove the items from the beginning. My question is about the performance of removing from the beginning of QVector.

Comment: (1) Why do you need a pointer to the raw data in your container? You could just heap-allocate your data, and store their pointers in the container. (2) The answer to virtually all performance questions is "Profile it"

Comment: Qt recommends to use `QList` instead `QVector`. In case when you need inset or remove items in the middle `QLinkedList` is the best. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/containers.html#the-container-classes read also this section: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/containers.html#algorithmic-complexity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this class to check `QVector::remove` performance:

```
#include <QDebug>

class Dummy
{
public:
    Dummy()
    {
        qDebug() << "dummy ctor" << ++c1;
    }

    Dummy(const Dummy &d)
    {
        qDebug() << "dummy copy ctor" << ++c2;
    }

    Dummy &operator=(const Dummy &d)
    {
        qDebug() << "dummy asign" << ++c3;
    }

    static int c1, c2, c3;
};

int Dummy::c1 = 0;
int Dummy::c2 = 0;
int Dummy::c3 = 0;
```

The test itself:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QVector<Dummy> v;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        v.append(Dummy());
    }

    qDebug() << "adding finished";

    v.remove(0);
    v.remove(v.size() - 1);

    qDebug() << "end";

        return 0;
}
```

In this example `Dummy` assign operator is called 99 times when you remove the first element, and it's not called at all when you remove the last one.

Anyway, I suppose you have some design problems if you need to access container raw data.
As JKSH said in comments, you can dynamically allocate memory for you data elements and then put those pointers into a container.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are looking for a data structure where the data is stored contiguously and, at the same time, you need to rearrange the data (i.e. remove element from the front). Unless you are removing all the elements in the vector, this operation will always require moving data to keep the vector contiguous.

One approach I can suggest to optimize the performance of your design (other than using lists instead of vectors and giving up on access-by-pointer) is to write a custom vector where removing the first element simply increments the `front` pointer and does not rearrange the data. This will have the same effect as removing the first element, but without the performance penalty. You will also have to implement a cleanup routine that will compact the vector once a certain threshold of removed elements is reached, but you can control when this cleanup is executed rather than having it execute on every removal from the queue.